# Why does my program not allow me a second input?

Tags: c

Suppose **savings** and **expenses** are variables of type double that have been given values. Write an if-else statement that outputs the word **Solvent**, decreases the value of Savings by the value of expenses and sets the value of expenses to 0, provided that savings is more than expenses. If however, savings is less than expenses, the if-else statement simply outputs the word **Bankrupt** and does not change the value of any variable.

**Specific question**: Why does my program skip immediately through after I type in a value for savings? How can I remedy it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void solvent();

int main(void)
{
   double savings, expenses;

   printf("\nEnter a number for savings: ");
   scanf("%2lf", &savings);
   printf("Enter a number for expenses: ");
   scanf("%2lf", &expenses);


   if(savings > expenses)
      solvent();
   else
      printf("Bankrupt!");

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

void solvent(double savings, double expenses)  
{
   printf("Solvent!");

   savings -= expenses;
   expenses = 0;
}
```

Comment: Stop using scanf.  Just stop.  It is a terrible function to try to learn at the same time that you are learning the language.  Pass parameters as command line arguments, and read inputs using `fread` and `fgets`.

Comment: This has to be a dupe; put a space in your `scanf` format to eat the whitespace.

Comment: Remove the `2` from `"%2lf"`. Function `scanf` has some similarities with `printf` but is different. Also, please see [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: @CarlNorum, `%lf` will skip whitespaces. The problem might be that the user is entering more than 2 digits.

Comment: @CarlNorum means donthis `scanf (&quot; %2lf&quot;, &amp;saving)`

Comment: @GRC those are [HTML entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). Neither C nor console output will recognise them.

Comment: I'd love to not use scanf(), but this work for a class and it's the only thing we've covered so far so I have to use it. Weather Vane, thank you for solving.

Comment: At least check the return value of any of the scanf family of functions, I'm sure that is not forbidden. If you don't, parse errors will lead to really confusing behavior, quite often even Undefined Behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for reasons I don't quite understand, making `%2lf` be just `%lf` was sufficient to fix this. Thanks to Weather Vane.

Comment: Reading the man pages will help you. The `scanf` and `printf` family functions are complicated, similar but different, so it will take some detailed study to understand them.

Comment: What's to understand? Printf takes a precision value for floats; scanf doesn't. That's how they're defined.